# Who is in this c.1866 photo?

Tags: 19th-century, identification, ottoman-empire

This photo was found with (but not in) an envelope containing seven photos of European royals, all but two of which have been positively identified (one of them [here](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/47891/who-is-this-young-prince) by Evargalo).

[image]

Below is a photo of the back. The card measures approximately 4 inches (10.16cm) by 2.5 inches (6.35cm) while the photo is about 3 inches by 2 inches.

[image]

The photographic studio indicated on the back belonged to [Emile Desmaisons](http://data.bnf.fr/14972831/emile_desmaisons/) (1812-80) and the photo probably dates from 1866 as

> Il a effectué des reproduction photographiques de lithographies. -
>   Ateliers à Paris : 5 rue des Grands Augustins (de 1861 à 1862) et 22
>   rue de l'Arbre Sec (1866)

*Translation: He made photographic reproductions of lithographs. - Workshops in Paris: 5 rue des Grands Augustins (from 1861 to 1862) and **22 rue de l'Arbre Sec (1866)***

Also, '1866' can be seen on the right side of the photo (near the man's left arm).

To my (very untutored) eye, the hat looks Turkish. I'm hoping the decorations / medals will enable someone to identify this man, or at least provide some clues as to who he might be.

---

*As with the other two photos I've posted questions about [here](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/47891/who-is-this-young-prince) and [here](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/47983/who-is-this-probably-royal-teenager), this photo belonged to my Great Grandmother (b. 1851). It was originally described to me as a photo of a Maharajah.*

Comment: That is a truly excellent hat.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It looks to be a photograph of [Abdül Aziz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abd%C3%BClaziz), the 32nd Sultan of the Ottoman Empire. He reigned between 25 June 1861 and 30 May 1876, which fits with the 1866 date.

Here is a [similar photograph](https://www.npg.org.uk/collections/search/portrait/mw158015/Abdul-Aziz?) by an unknown photographer from the National Portrait gallery collection:

[image: Abdul Aziz by Unknown photographer]

- © National Portrait Gallery, London, Creative commons licence [CC BY-NC-ND 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/3.0/)

Comment: You have beaten me for 10 minutes. Also, the 8 points star looks like the medal of the Order of the Garter, and [from the list of their members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Knights_and_Ladies_of_the_Garter), by 1866 Abdul Aziz and his father Abdul Medjid (whose face is too different to match) would have been the only non Christian members

Comment: @SJuan76 That was also my thinking.  Abdül Aziz was the only one who matched the date.

Comment: Looks like you've got it. If he has the Order of the Garter, the photo can't be before 1867.